# Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'string' error

Tags: c#, linq

Why do I see the aforementioned error with this bit of code? The error specifically occurs in the `t.TerritoryID == territoryID` section:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(EmployeeViewModel employee, string[] territories)
{
        ModelState.Remove("territories");

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (territories != null)
            {
                employee.Territories = territories.Select(territoryID => repository.Territories.FirstOrDefault(t => t.TerritoryID == territoryID));
            }

            employee.EmployeeID = repository.CreateEmployee(employee);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

In case you're wondering, `TerritoryID` is an integer. Any suggestions on how I can rectify this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Convert the int to a string first or the string to an int first.

Comment: Because `territories` is a string array.

Comment: `t => t.TerritoryID.ToString() == territoryID` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Int and string are two different types, you can't directly compare them. You can convert an int to a string or vice versa.

Change `territories` to an int array: `var territoriesInt = territories.Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray()`, and then use that.

The above code is string to int conversion. This can fail if a string doesn't contain a number. I prefer to let it fail on purpose if someone sends bad data. It can be done the opposite way, too, if you compare your territories strings to `territoryID.ToString()`.